# Sinatra Set Configuration File on Heroku

Tags: heroku, sinatra

I have been struggling for the last couple hours with this question, and I hope someone can help me out. I'm creating my first Sinatra app and I would like to use Mongo as the backend.  I have decided to use Heroku's MongoLab service, and it gave me a connection URI to use to connect with Mongo from within my Sinatra app. This does not seem like the type of info I want to keep in Version Control, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to not hardcode it into the application. On one hand the key is stored permanently as a Heroku ENV var, but that does not help when I'm developing locally. I've tried creating a config file as outlined here: http://www.miqueloliete.com/configuring-environment-variables-in-sinatra/, but it only helps locally. I can't seem to find the way to do this.

Thanks in advance,
Ryan

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve these so I can just give you ideas.

**Env**

You can set the enviroment variable on your local pc with `export name=mongourl`

**configuration**

Sinatra provide a way to use different configuration sections. That is what I do normaly. Like these:

```
configuration :development do         
     setup things to use your local db
end
```

```
configuration :production do
    setup things for production db
end
```

**config file**

Store these informations in a yaml file.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the best way to do it for me. I didn't realize that in Ruby ENV['somevar'] accessed your environmental variables for your shell, so in order to not commit my secret keys and passwords to version control, I just make sure that all my environmental variables that I had in my Heroku (the results of heroku config) were also variables in my shell.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [dotenv gem](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) and then create a .env file locally that has the same keys as your Heroku ENV variables. That way you can keep the same environment keys in your code for both environments, and choose to have identical or different values, as needed.

```
#app.rb
require 'sinatra/base'
...

if Sinatra::Base.environment == :development
    require 'dotenv'
    Dotenv.load
end

#.env
DATABASE_URL=mongo_sinatra_connection_info
```